# Microsoft Access Sql query output a different currency symbol

Tags: ms-access, format, union, currency

A sql union of 2 tables in Microsoft Access with amount field in £ is returning the outputs with Euro symbol instead of £.
Any idea on why and how I can change the outputs to £ symbol?

Comment: May be `FORMAT()` function can help.

Answer (score 0):

A currency value isn't saved with any symbol and knows nothing about pounds or dollars.

The symbol is applied if you use the default format for display, thus, your current currency (from Windows) is apparently Euro.

Use custom code to disply other currency symbols.

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.

Comment: Note that using code (e.g. the `format` function) influences the ability to filter and sort the result as a numeric value. You can also define the format in the query designer, column properties. For union queries, however, the designer is unavailable, so you can put the union in a subquery.